# rewrite function using jQuery .delegate()

Tags: jquery, modernizr

I have [this working code](http://jsfiddle.net/LpESM/) which adds placeholder functionality for browsers that don't already have it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //show placeholder text when browser doesn't support placeholder attribute
    if(!Modernizr.input.placeholder){
        $('[placeholder]').focus(function() {
          var input = $(this);
          if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
            input.val('');
            input.removeClass('placeholder');
          }
        }).blur(function() {
          var input = $(this);
          if (input.val() == '' || input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
            input.addClass('placeholder');
            input.val(input.attr('placeholder'));
          }
        }).blur();
        $('[placeholder]').parents('form').submit(function() {
          $(this).find('[placeholder]').each(function() {
            var input = $(this);
            if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
              input.val('');
            }
          });
        });

    }
});
```

The issue is that if I dynamically add fields with placeholders, the above code does not display them. FF shows the new placeholders but IE does not. My understanding is that I need to use `.delegate()` if I want jQuery to monitor both current and future DOM elements. So I tried rewriting my function as below.  Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VbjV2/1/).  Unfortunately, the new version acts on neither existing nor dynamically added placeholders.  What did I do wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    if(!Modernizr.input.placeholder){
        $('form').delegate('[placeholder]','focus',function() {
          var input = $(this);
          if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
            input.val('');
            input.removeClass('placeholder');
          }
        }).delegate('[placeholder]','blur', function() {
          var input = $(this);
          if (input.val() == '' || input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
            input.addClass('placeholder');
            input.val(input.attr('placeholder'));
          }
        }).blur();
        $('[placeholder]').parents('form').submit(function() {
          $(this).find('[placeholder]').each(function() {
            var input = $(this);
            if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
              input.val('');
            }
          });
        });

    }
});
```

Comment: There isn't a way to effectively track when new elements are added to the page other than using depreciated features that aren't supported in all browsers, or using a `setInterval`. I suggest instead abstracting this code behind a function and running it on target elements rather than `[placeholder]` when new elements are added to the page. `.delegate` won't help you in this case.

Comment: @KevinB: well that's an easy solution! I'm not clear on why there isn't a way to effectively track new elements though. Is it because the criterion is an attribute instead of an element?

Comment: The biggest issue with the DOMMutationEvents was that they were very inefficient and could cause performance issues due to the fact that it triggered for way more events than you usually needed. A setInterval checking for the existence of new elements is a little better, but still requires running a `$()` every iteration which is a big waste. The most effective way to solve this is to run the code yourself when the new elements are added.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the .on() event http://api.jquery.com/on/? If you read from "Direct and delegated events" downwards it explains how it works. I think it should solve your issue. I use it for similar issues when using logicless templating like handlebars.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    if(!Modernizr.input.placeholder){
        $('form').on('focus', '[placeholder]',function() {
          var input = $(this);
          if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
            input.val('');
            input.removeClass('placeholder');
          }
        }).on('blur', '[placeholder]', function() {
          var input = $(this);
          if (input.val() == '' || input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
            input.addClass('placeholder');
            input.val(input.attr('placeholder'));
          }
        }).blur();
        $('[placeholder]').parents('form').submit(function() {
          $(this).find('[placeholder]').each(function() {
            var input = $(this);
            if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
              input.val('');
            }
          });
        });

    }
});
```

Comment: as you can see in this jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/tyTTF/1/), `.on` does not work either. Thanks though.